provideHttpClient "Type 'EnvironmentProviders' is not assignable to type 'Provider'. Error in Angular 18
I am working on an Angular 18 application and was getting errors from the deprecated HttpClientModule so I moved to provideHttpClient and keep getting the following error:
Type 'EnvironmentProviders' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
app.component.ts
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { provideHttpClient, withFetch } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet],
  providers: [provideHttpClient(withFetch())],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'chat-frontend';
}

app.config.ts
import { ApplicationConfig, provideZoneChangeDetection } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideHttpClient, withFetch } from '@angular/common/http';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideClientHydration(),
    provideHttpClient(withFetch())
  ]
};


main.ts
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { provideHttpClient, withFetch } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { routes } from './app/app.routes';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideHttpClient(withFetch())
  ]
}).catch(err => console.error(err));

main.server.ts
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { config } from './app/app.config.server';
import { provideHttpClient, withFetch } from '@angular/common/http';

const bootstrap = () => bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, config);

export default bootstrap;



where exactly are you getting this from . which file ?

If you add provideHttpClient at the bootstrapApplication it is provided throughout the application.
If you provide here it applies to all child modules that are lazy loaded also -> stackblitz example
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { provideHttpClient, withFetch } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet],
  providers: [], // <- remove this!
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'chat-frontend';
}

